# Razor pages - CRUD not generated for Single navigation property

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, relationship, crud, razor-pages

I'm following the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key). The part entitled "Single navigation property" which I implemented:

```
    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

along with (in the DBContext):

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .HasMany(b => b.Posts)
        .WithOne();
}
```

Then I created the migration 'add-migration InitialCreate) and I updated the database (update-database), the first thing I noticed is that in the the database I have found only two created tables "Blog" and "Post" but no relation is created between them.

then, I generated the CRUD for blogs and posts. my biggest issue is here : in the page created for blogs creation, I don't have a choice/user entry for list of posts (I only have a user entry field for URL).

Please your advice about the issue? because I'm confused if its really possible or not to have a CRUD for a List type.

Comment: Did you read this - "While it is recommended to have a foreign key property defined in the dependent entity class" - your relations are  good if you need a simple select query. If you need CRUD you have to add all properties to your model explicitly, otherwise you will have to do CRUD manually and  use very strange code for it. Nothing is free in this world.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the quote. I understand.So i have to modify manually the generated CRUD in ordrer to somehow take into consideration populating a third table which will indicate the posts for each blog.